# Perl: Calculate number of days by converting to seconds

Tags: perl

I am trying to calculate the number of calendar days between two dates extracted from a database.  I thought that converting the dates to seconds would be a simple and correct solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Date::Parse;

my $minDate = "2016-03-27";
my $maxDate = "2016-06-15";

print "Format as extracted from db: mindate: $minDate and maxdate: $maxDate\n"; 

my ($dbYear,$dbMonth,$dbDay) = split ('-', $minDate);
my $datum = "$dbYear$dbMonth$dbDay";
my $minDateSec = str2time($datum);

($dbYear,$dbMonth,$dbDay) = split ('-', $maxDate);
$datum = "$dbYear$dbMonth$dbDay";
my $maxDateSec = str2time($datum);

my $numCalDaysSec = ($maxDateSec-$minDateSec)/86400;

print "Min date in Seconds: $minDateSec\n";
print "Max date in Seconds: $maxDateSec\n";
print "Num days: $numCalDaysSec\n";
```

Initially, I thought that this method provided me with reliable results:

```
bash-3.2$ ./testNumDays.pl
As extracted from db: mindate: 2016-06-14 and maxdate: 2016-06-15
Min date in Seconds: 1465855200
Max date in Seconds: 1465941600
Num days: 1
bash-3.2$ ./testNumDays.pl
As extracted from db: mindate: 2016-05-31 and maxdate: 2016-06-15
Min date in Seconds: 1464645600
Max date in Seconds: 1465941600
Num days: 15
bash-3.2$ ./testNumDays.pl
As extracted from db: mindate: 2016-03-28 and maxdate: 2016-06-15
Min date in Seconds: 1459116000
Max date in Seconds: 1465941600
Num days: 79
bash-3.2$ ./testNumDays.pl
As extracted from db: mindate: 2016-03-27 and maxdate: 2016-06-15
Min date in Seconds: 1459033200
Max date in Seconds: 1465941600
Num days: 79.9583333333333
bash-3.2$
```

Obviously, the number of calendar dates between dates should be an integer.  Mmmm, what I am doing wrong?  Why is converting to seconds not reliable?

Since I am a Perl newbie, I am probably overlooking the obvious.  Any help is therefore more than welcome.

Comment: Why not do this directly in your database query?

Comment: In fact I am learning how to handle dates in Perl. Curiosity and familiarisation with Perl are the main drivers.

Comment: Looks like a Daylight Saving Time error.  I haven't checked my calendar to see if that's the problem.

Comment: @Ga Mmeeu, Using `str2time($datum, 'UTC')` (even if it's a local time) instead of `str2time($datum)` will give the right answer. This is the trick Time::Piece uses. But don't do that. Use a module designed for Date arithmetic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use the [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) Core module:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Time::Piece qw();

my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime('2016-03-27', '%Y-%m-%d');
my $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime('2016-06-15', '%Y-%m-%d');
my $seconds = $t2 - $t1;
print $seconds->days(), "\n";
```

Output:

```
80
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime). It's not in Core, but it's often very handy. Because it doesn't parse dates, we quickly made our own parsing function.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;
my $minDate = "2016-03-27";
my $maxDate = "2016-06-15";

sub parse {
    my $date = shift;

    my ( $y, $m, $d ) = split /-/, $date;

    return DateTime->new( year => $y, month => $m, day => $d );
}

my $days = parse($minDate)->delta_days(parse($maxDate))->in_units('days');
print $days;

__END__

80
```

Comment: It does parse dates. DateTime::Format::Strptime is the most flexible, but DateTime::Format::ISO8601 is probably the simplest in this case.

Comment: @ikegami yeah if you load one of those. But it [does say _this module does not parse dates_](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#Parsing-Dates)... ;)

Comment: By that logic, DateTime doesn't know anything about time zones because all that time zone information is in another distribution. That's rather silly.

Comment: It's not my logic. I was just quoting. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You are making the invalid assumption that every day is 86,400 seconds long.

Please go to http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2016.html and look at all of the places where Daylight Saving Time (aka Summer Time) starts on 27 Mar 2016.  That day is not 86,400 seconds long.